# Regex vertical bar

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to find all matches for these in 1 go:

```
http://somewebsite/usr/blah_blah

http://somewebsite/ch/blah_blah_blah
```

I've tried using vertical bar but no go

```
matches = re.findall('http://somewebsite/(usr|ch)/(.*?)', line, re.DOTALL)
```

Instead of doing 2 separate regex, I'd like to have blah_blah and blah_blah_blah with just one above regex using vertical bar (OR)

Any suggestion? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should remove that white space before `http` in your `regex`.. try it

Comment: @helpme What's your expected output?

Comment: sorry for a white space - typo

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the whole line starting from `http` link, then you have to do two things.

1. Remove the space which exists before `http` in your regex.
2. Turn all the capturing groups into non-capturing groups.
3. Turn non-greedy regex to greey.

So your regex must be,

```
matches = re.findall(r'\bhttp://somewebsite/(?:usr|ch)/.*', line, re.DOTALL)
```

If you want to fetch only the part which exists after `usr` or `ch` then apply the capturing group only to the following `.*`

```
matches = re.findall(r'\bhttp://somewebsite/(?:usr|ch)/(.*)', line, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a bunch. Sorry for white space typo. (.*) and ?: do the trick. Have a great day.

Comment: @helpme I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that need to be done. As was mentioned, remove the white space it is treated as if there was a white space. Next, you failed to escape the / character. Finally the question mark character tells the expression to stop looking at some spot. Try the following.

```
 matches = re.findall('http:\/\/somewebsite\/(usr|ch)\/.*', line, re.DOTALL)
```

Finally the parenthesis can be used to captcha data. Leave it out if you want the full address. In python group 0 will have the full match. The same is true in java and most other languages.This appears to be python so [x[0] for x in matches] will give a list of the entire link.

More info is available at the following [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to give you a more general example; the actually most adequate solution might depend on some information, that is not given yet:

```
    test1 = "xxx http://somewebsite/usr/blah_blah/baff_blaff"
    test2 = "yyy http://somewebsite/log/blah_blah_blah"
    test3 = "zzzzhttp://somewebsite/ch/blah_blah_blah_blah/ ZZZ"

    matches = re.findall(r'http://somewebsite/(?:usr|ch)/(\w*)', test1 + '\n' + test2 + '\n' + test3)

    print(matches)


>>> ['blah_blah', 'blah_blah_blah_blah']
```